# Upload and embed video playing in desktop browser but not playing in mobile browser

Tags: html, css, video, browser

I have embed a video in my site. http://www.vaatasmart.com/application

I have embed with following code. And its playing in desktop browser and not playing in mobile browser.

HTML

```
<div id="container">
<video width="3000" height="380" loop autoplay="autoplay" />
    <source id="mp4" src="https://vaatasmart.squarespace.com/s/hv.mp4" type="video/mp4" />
</video>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
html, body {
   padding: 0;
   margin: 0;
   background-color: #efefef;
}
#container {
   padding: 0;
   margin: 0;
   height: 300px;
   width: 580px;
   background-color: white;
   display: block;
   overflow: hidden;
   position: relative;
}

video {
   padding: 0;
   margin: 0;
   width: 600px;
   position: absolute;
   top: -40px;
   left: -10px;
}
```

Comment: Your video also not play in PC: firefox-37.0.1 version.

Comment: But i don't face any issue with PC. Its working in all PC browser.

Comment: OS: Ubuntu 14.04m Browser: firefox-37.0.1 not able to display/see your video. I will back soon with solution for your problem.

Comment: which browser are you using in mobile...

Answer (score 0):

Source : [html5 video on mobile](http://html5hub.com/html5-video-on-mobile-a-primer/)

If you’re embedding HTML5 pages with video inside an iOS or Android app, things get a bit more complicated.

**iOS UIWebView**
To support playing HTML5 video inline, which is the default elsewhere, you need to set the `allowsInlineMediaPlayback` property, and include the `webkit-playsinline` attribute on the video tag, otherwise the video will play in the default media player.

You also need to set the `mediaPlaybackRequiresUserAction` to NO in order to support autoplay.

**Android WebView**
Android WebView requires some explicit settings in order to support HTML5 video. You need to enable hardware acceleration (add `android:hardwareAccelerated="true"` to your `AndroidManifest.xml` file) and set **WebChromeClient** on your WebView.

There are certainly a lot of things to consider when implementing HTML5 video for mobile, but steady improvements in browser support is making it easier for you to give your users seamless in-browser video playback.

Hope this help you.